# Visual Studio Code Formatting fail on save

Tags: react-native, formatting, save, visual-studio-code

I've started learning React Native.

I'm using Visual Studio Code as my editor.

I've set up the boiler plate and started the app. But whenever I change a .js file and hit save, VSCode is messing up all the formatting.

[image: Before save]
[image: After save]

I thought I could sort this in the settings.json file but after googling for a while and playing around I can't find the correct setting.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Setting file is default one:

[image]

UPDATE: I re-installed vscode. Then set up a basic js file with a react native tag and a html tag. I added in:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"javascript.format.enable": false
```

To my settings.json file and the problem still occurs:

[image: pre save]
[image: post save]

The problem is having tags in a js file, I just don't know how to tell vscode to ignore them?

Comment: Please add info inside `settings.json` file.

Comment: @jose920405 updated

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I found out what this was by looking though the extensions. Thanks to @wgj for the hint.

Turns out it was the JS-CSS-HTML formatter. I looked through the instructions and have removed the auto save for now. I'll have to work out the specific settings for this.

It uses js-beautify so if anyone knows the settings I should be looking at would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem and it turned out my ultimate culprit was...

[image: js-beautify for VS Code by HookQR]

So I simply disabled it for the workspace.

Answer (score 8):

Same here, all my HTML format messed up after saving, I disable "JS-CSS-HTML Formatter" and problem solved

Answer (score 7):

In the end, what did the trick was changing the file format from JavaScript to JavaScript React on the bottom toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

All my HTML format messed up in js after saving, I disable "JS-CSS-HTML Formatter" and restarted vscode, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I found my solution to this problem by **converting my components file extension from js to jsx**. No more issues and everything is working fine.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 3):

1. Disable js-css-html formatter.
2. if you are using prettier and beautify together, override the setting as :

```
"beautify.ignore": [
        "**/*.js",
        "**/*.jsx"
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Prettier Code Formatter instead of Beautify. Works perfectly for language mode Babel JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You should search for "format" in `settings.json`. You'll find a whole lot of TypeScript/JavaScript formatting tweaks in there, but the one that stands out to me is:

```
  // Defines space handling after opening and before closing non empty brackets.
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBrackets": false
```

Alternative, you're not a fan of formatting at all, you can turn it off entirely:

```
  // Enable/disable default JavaScript formatter.
  "javascript.format.enable": true,
```

However, a lot of my formatting options come from language server extensions, so if you're using one for React Native specifically, be sure to check the attributes in `settings.json`, or the docs to see if there are any attributes you can add.

Comment: I've tried both of these to no avail. I have noticed that formatting the file (`CTRL + SHIFT + F`) gives the same result as the save. See updated question

Comment: Interesting observation about the tags. Do you have any extensions for HTML? Maybe they're being too aggressive. Also, silly thing to check for, but in your screenshots it looks like settings.json needed to be saved.

Comment: Yeah I did save it. You're right, it was an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Add this on `settings.json` file. Whether you are using any extension or not, use this code. It works fine for me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** Just Disable JS-CSS-HTML Formatter

**Solution 2:** Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+**<kbd>,</kbd>** (open settings) after that search `Code formatted` and change *none --> Prettier*

If you don't have `prettier` install from the extension's marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

i just had this problem , apparently its because of the beautify/prettier , try to disable both , then restart Vs code (your editor) . but then  if u really want to use prettier , go under its extension settings and make sure its in strict with whitespaces and toogle around a few other settings and you should be fine , cheers .

Answer (score 0):

Just turning off format on save option from the settings would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can select JavaScript React in the task bar under Select Language Mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following

1. uninstall other formatters which are not required. To check how many formatters you have just press ctrl + shift + p or command +shift + p (mac) and type format document after that a menu will appear showing you your formatters
2. press ctrl + shift + p or command +shift + p (mac) and type settings and click on open users settings and then search for format on save and check the box

that's it!!

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

changing the file format from JavaScript to JavaScript React on the bottom toolbar worked just fine for me

Answer (score -1):

I have tried all methods but the problem is solved completely by this:
-> Open setting.json
-> "files.associations": {
        "*.js": "javascriptreact"
    }
->Add above lines and press save the problem will solve

Answer (score -2):

You can type the following command string when creating your project

```
npx create-react-app name-of-app react-complete-guide
```

or the following, if you have create-react-app installed already

```
create-react-app name-of-app   react-complete-guide
```