# Visual studio autosave

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When ever I write html code in js with auto save it provides space automatically, Any one help me with the error.

[image]

Comment: You cant write html in js,you can write only jsx,soltion for your issue,turn of auto save.

Comment: Also this is a question for superuser

Comment: Dupe of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149100/visual-studio-code-formatting-fail-on-save

Comment: You can not write HTML directly into JavaScript, but you can EMBED HTML into JavaScript by making it an ES6 template-string which means putting the HTML between back-quotes (`)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I think what you're trying to do is to return HTML from a JavaScript function.

A good way to do that would be to enclose the HTML into back-quotes (`). That would make it a JavaScript "template string". Template-strings can contain line-breaks and even "placeholders" so they are a great way to mix JavaScript and HTML and other markup languages. So your code could look something like:

```
return `<p>
Hello
</p>
`;
```