# VS Code python separates items in parentheses

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a line of code like so:

[image]

It has a comment after the line, when I hit `Command + S` to save it turns out to this:

[image]

How can I edit the JSON settings file to stop this behaviour? I couldn't find an answer anywhere. It only happens if there are comments in the end of the line.

Comment: it could be the JS-CSS-HTML formatter or whatever the python equivalent is.  is this similar to your problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149100/visual-studio-code-formatting-fail-on-save

Comment: It could be trying to make sure your lines are under 80 characters long. The comment pushes it over 80 characters.

Comment: Probably some setting about maximum line length? PEP8 linter limiting lines at 79 characters?

Comment: See: editor.formatOnSave in preferences.

Comment: I would like it to format on save when I write Python, but not in this manner.

Comment: Move the comment to above the line of code.  Your line of code will no longer be too long.

Comment: I set the max lines to 200 and it still wraps it, so its not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used `"editor.formatOnSave": true,` in "`settings.json`", I also encountered the problem of line wrapping.

Then I commented out this setting:

[image]

My `settings.json`:

> ```
> {
>   "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
>     "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
>     "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
>     "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
>     "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
> }
> ```

It is recommended that you comment out the relevant formatting, editing style, and saving style settings in the settings to avoid affecting the style of the code. In addition, please reload VSCode after setting.